# How can I make a game over like funcrion that triggers when a variable reaches 0?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I tried to do something like

```
 public double number = 10000;
 public double decreasing = 10;

 public void Update()
 {
     number -= decreasing * Time.deltaTime;

     if (number == 0)
     {
         decreasing = 0;
     }
 }
```

but this doesn't work. How can I make it stop decreasing when it reaches 0?

Comment: When asking a question, you should state the expected and actual behavior. How does it "not work"? Perhaps `number` is *less than* zero after the subtraction? If so, the condition should be `if (number <= 0)`

Comment: When the number reaches 0, it continues to substract. I tried using the Debug.Log, but it didn't show anything when the number reached 0.

Comment: Are you sure the number actually becomes `0` exactly after the subtraction? What if it starts at `1`, and then we subtract `10`? Try changing the operator to `<=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a double, a form of rather big floating point number. Floats are known for their inprecision. A **exact** match like `number == 0` happens once in a blue moon. Even after setting it to a value, it is not guaranteed to be *precisely* that value. This is a inherent, unavoidbale property of floating point types: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0

Either expect it from now on and use <= checks, or stop using float altogether. Some simple code like this:

```
if(number <= 0)
  number = 0;
```

will make sure that if it ever drops below 0, it will be seet back to 0. After this line, a exact match like `number == 0` will be somewhat reliable. But my advice stands to just stop using a float altogether. A int where you display the last 3 digits as "decimal point" works way better here.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I used 1000 as an example, but my number should be able to store values at least as high at 10^15, so I can't actually use an int

Comment: @RaduPîrvu 10^15 is easily within the range of a long - 64 bit integer. Indeed it goes up to 10^18. And if you need even higher, there is BigInt.